# Problem running Spring boot graalvm native image on AWS Lambda using container image

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, graalvm-native-image, aws-lambda-containers

I created simple spring boot application with a REST end point. I was able to create the native image using mvn spring-boot:build-image. The image is created and I am able to run it locally using docker.

I created the AWS Lambda function using this container image. I am getting an exception as this function is being created and it ends in FAILED state.

**Error**

Failed to create the function TestAgainAgain: Image runtime config size is larger than 16 KB. ImageConfigSize: 447.53 KB

Any clue on how to avoid/solve the above error will be appreciated

Comment: Could it be that you have a lot of environment variables set in your runtime config or that their values are large?

Comment: Hi @Jens 
I do not have any runtime variables set in the spring boot app.

Answer (score 0):

Documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

```
Container image settings size 16 KB
```

It seems that the whole Config element is taken from the container.
If you inspect your image like so:

```
docker inspect <your image> |jq -c '.[].Config' |wc
```

At least in my case this is close to the size in the error message from AWS.

It seems due to paketo build packs adding a lot of labels.

I don't have a good solution other than switching to another build tool such as JIB for now.